# Windows defender just removed sudo on my debian WSL, can I restore this?

Tags: debian, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-defender

So basically, i restarted my laptop and got the latest security updates. When i logged into my debian WSL i tried to do a sudo command and got a pop up from windows defender. Windows defender found a trojan horse called Win64/Longage.

[image: Defender then removed libsudo_util.so.0.0.0.]

I've already revoked and allowed the "trojan" but still libsudo_util.so.0.0.0 is gone. Is there a way to fix this problem?

Comment: There is a [related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1194884/how-to-replace-libapt-private-so-0-0-0-manually-on-ubuntu-for-windows) on askubuntu. Perhaps you find some of the answers or comments there helpful.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what i'm searching for

Comment: See this thread https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4745. The issue has been fixed internally at Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

For any future visitors I solved the problem.

libsudo_util.so.0.0.0 was actually revoked by windows defender and put back where it was supposed to be. While in the subsystem the file was not visible, but if you visit the location by the explorer the file is actually there. I found an explanation for this [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/1152).

> In short, this is expected behavior: Native Linux files require metadata (such as POSIX file permissions) that Windows applications do not understand. %localappdata%\lxss is meant to be opaque data storage for WSL; you're not intended to work with it directly. (Hence its location in %localappdata%.)

So since Windows Defender removed it, and then put it back, WSL did not recognize that the file was back.

So I copied the file to my C:\ drive. Then I copied the file inside my WSL from the C:\ drive back to /usr/lib/sudo

Unless you're already logged into your WSL as root, you're not able to do this. You can set your WSL to login as root via PowerShell.

In PowerShell execute the following command `debian config --default-user root`
You can change debian to ubuntu or another distro.